# How to I Change node version in windows?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I'm Using nvm-windows.
Tried change node version, But It doesn't work for me.
It Seems like nvm is not change global node.

How Can I switching node version?

[image]

Comment: does this answer your question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-windows#:~:text=Install%20the%20latest%20stable%20LTS,%2C%20ie%3A%20nvm%20install%2012.14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstall and reinstall nvm. Make sure to do this before reinstalling:

**Uninstall existing node**
Please note, you need to uninstall any existing versions of node.js before installing NVM for Windows. Also delete any existing nodejs installation directories (e.g., "C:\Program Files\nodejs") that might remain. NVM's generated symlink will not overwrite an existing (even empty) installation directory.

**Uninstall existing npm**
You should also delete the existing npm install location (e.g. "C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm"), so that the nvm install location will be correctly used instead. Backup the global npmrc config (e.g. C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc), if you have some important settings there, or copy the settings to the user config C:\Users<user>.npmrc.

Comment: Thank you :) I was not removed "C : \ Users <user> \ AppData \ Roaming \ npm-cache".

Answer (score 5):

Install nvm. In nvm you can install all node version, and you can change it very easy. :)

Example

```
nvm list
nvm install 10.0.0
nvm list
nvm use 10.0.0
```

And you using node 10.0.0 :)